# Is there a construct like "the fuck" in Spanish?

Tags: coloquialismos

In colloquial English, the phrase "the fuck" can be added to questions as an intensifier, for example:

- "How the fuck did you do that?" conveys greater confusion than "How did you do that?"
- "Who the fuck is that?" conveys greater hostility than "Who is that?"

I'm already aware of a few phrases, but they seem to be specific to "what" questions:

- ¿Qué carajo están haciendo en mi cama?

How would I do something similar for all questions in Spanish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in Spain I think that the equivalent is "coño".

According to the DRAE

[**coño**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AiQvxdq)

> 5. interj. **malson**. U. para expresar diversos estados de ánimo, especialmente extrañeza o enfado.

Let me translate:

> used to express different moods, specially strangeness or angriness.
>   malson. = malsonante - rude

As pointed by @walen, **cojones** is a perfect synonym in this context and you can use it too

[**cojones**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9ieEiku)

> 1. interj. malson. coloq. U. para expresar diversos estados de ánimo, especialmente extrañeza o enfado.

---

Notice that **carajo** will suit you as well for the same purpose. It's not specific to "what" questions.

[**carajo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7PHLd6o)

> 1. interj. malson. U. para expresar sorpresa, contrariedad, etc.

Using your examples

> How the fuck did you do that? 
>  ¿Cómo coño hiciste eso? 
>  ¿Cómo cojones hiciste eso? 
> ¿Cómo carajo
>   hiciste eso?
>
> Who the fuck is that?
>  ¿Quién coño es ese? 
>  ¿Quién cojones es ese?
> ¿Quién carajo es ese?

Comment: @walen You're right, sir. Editing ...

Comment: ¿se usa carajo en España? Apoyo esa versión en cuanto a Latinoamérica

Comment: @user2325442 La verdad es que no la he oido mucho. La he mencionado más que nada porque el OP dudaba sobre su uso en este caso.

Answer (score 3):

In the Spanish of Argentina the corresponding intensifier is *mierda* ("shit"). It's not a specially strong word (but in turn I sense that English *fuck* is not as strong as it must have been, and certainly not as strong as the corresponding terms in Spanish). It works more-or-less the same as the other words that have been already mentioned, such as *coño, cojones, carajo, diablos, demonios*:

- *¿Qué mierda hiciste?*
- *¿Para qué mierda me llamaste?*
- *¿Quién mierda te dijo que podías hablar?*

Unless *coño* and *cojones*, which are rather specific of Spain, *mierda* is universally recognized (even if not as an intensifier). Also, unlike *diablos* and *demonios*, it's a real *mala palabra* (swear- or taboo word) of the kind you'd rather have your toddler not scream in polite company.

Comment: I agree with @walen.  I guess to find something equivalent to *f---* one would have to reach for *puta madre*, e.g. *Qué puta madre hiciste*.

Comment: Thanks. In Argentina there's no standard use of sex-related profanity in this particular syntactic slot (i.e. after question words), even if there's a lot of it in other places.

Comment: @walen I'm assuming your comment about the middle R refers to my fellow denizen Roberto Fontanarrosa's speech about *[las malas palabras](https://youtu.be/r7GYWYc1Xi4?t=65)*.

Comment: I agree with the shorter semantic closeness of *puta* (rather than  *mierda* to match the fuck) but still *carajo* works better than those.  In Argentina there are synonyms of *carajo*  —as the male organ —which sound as strong as *fuck* (probably for not being so naturalized over time), like *pingo* (in the northwest region) or *poronga*,  or *choto* (through-out the country)

Comment: @user2325442 That's true, but those are not intended for the same purpose as English *fuck* in *Wh-... the fuck...?*; they mostly mean the same as *mierda* in affirmative sentences (*Lo que hiciste fue una...*), i.e. "something bad", not an intensifier.

Comment: No @pablo76, what i say is that the also do act as intensifiers. In the sense that they don't modify the meaning —just as the word fuck  is used to spice-up what is being said, to be emphatic about the meaning and intend of a phrase

Answer (score 2):

Mexico (and other places -- not sure if it's universal):

> ¿Qué diablos está pasando con StackExchange?
>
> ¿Cómo diablos hicieron para provocar tal relajo?
>
> ¿Quién diablos tomó la decisión de despedir a Monica Cellio?

Variant: *demonios* instead of *diablos*.

Note that these are not at the same level of vulgarity as *f---*.  But they still provide a good punch.

Comment: @Charlie - Oh, okay.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well, I think that "diablos" or "demonios" are the equivalent of "the hell" expression. Who the hell is that man? What the hell is happening with StackExchange?" I have read then in books translated from English mainly. Do Mexicans use it or they prefer "carajo" instead?

Comment: @RubioRic - I think  they're both popular.  I guess *diablos* is the softest of these three, meaning, it's the one your preteen can copy from you and not get in trouble at school for.